# How do I get one monitor on top of the other?

Tags: 10.10, multiple-monitors

I'm using a laptop and a monitor (wall mounted) over my laptop. I would like to reflect this physical hardware setup in my software screen setup. So that I can move my mouse upward, out of my laptop screen and use the monitor on the wall. I have been searching for a solution for a while, and I hope somone can help me out.

I'm using Ubuntu 10.10 "out of the box". Side by side screen setups works just fine, over/under is doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "Monitors" application under System/Prefences and just drag the right hand monitor above the left hand monitor. Click apply and you're done.

Comment: Unless you're using nvidia, at which point you can't.

Comment: Thanks for your help, life is better now. For me it didn't work  like you suggested, probably because of different hardware setup, but motivated by knowing you made it work I tried various ways of changing the screens until I "hit the right combination". After mirroring screens, unmirroring the screens again, wich led to differet resolution (not correct), then moving the monitor over the laptop screen and finalizing with resetting to the correct resolutions for both screens